# php loop auto increment variables

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop in php and that works fine, I already

```
$c=0;
$d=1;
while($c <=23){
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(amperagem) AS soma FROM tomada WHERE HOUR(data) >= '$c'     AND HOUR(data) < '$d' AND YEAR(data)='$ano' AND MONTH(data)='$mes' AND     DAY(data)='$diaOntem'" ;
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_BOTH);
    $amper= $row['soma'];        

    // on the end off loop I have
    $d++;// that variable increment just one time
    $c++; //that variable autoincrement fine

}
```

so the problem is with variable "d" it increase one time.

What is the problem?

inside the While I have 23 ifs like that

```
if  ($c=0){
$calcAmperagemHora00=$amper;//soma as medições de consumo
}
  if  ($c=1){
$calcAmperagemHora01=$amper;//soma as medições de consumo
}
```

Comment: Add `echo $d;` before you increment it? What do you get?

Comment: There's no way this code could do that. I suspect you haven't copied it correctly.

Comment: @barmar is right - this code DOES work, tried and tested. (without the SQL stuff)

Comment: Your `if` statements are wrong. They should use `==` to compare things, not `=`.

Comment: If you have `if ($d = 1)` it will set the variable back to `1`

Comment: thanks Barmar, works now

Comment: @RobertoBahia I think you can delete this Q here, since it only was a simple typo which doesn't serve anyone

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved change `=` to `==`

```
if  ($c==0){
}

if  ($c==1){
}
```